# When checking out a previous commit, why are some files are in state 'deleted', instead of having a clean status?

Tags: git

I have a repository, where if I start from a clean `git status` and check out a commit (actually a tag), git status shows that some files have state `deleted`, and in fact those commits are missing from the disk. If I `git reset --hard`, those files are brought back. I don't understand why those files aren't revived automatically when I check out the commit?

Comment: Why do you think, that you should have clean state after checkout if you does not have clean state before it? It seems [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout-emgitcheckoutem--detachltcommitgt) suggest quite opposite: *Local modifications to the files in the working tree are kept, so that the resulting working tree will be the state recorded in the commit plus the local modifications.*

Comment: Sorry, should have stated that. I have clean state before executing the checkout.

Comment: If you can provide a [mcve] we can probably explain it... (The description sounds like something that can't / shouldn't happen.)